# find the index of an array function in excel

Tags: excel

I have been working on a shortest path problem in excel (see image below) with dynamic programming.
I got the numbers. However, I can't find a way to also find the index of the minimum number the path belongs to.

The formula loops over the row and column element-wise, and adds them together. Finally, it fins the minimum value.

For example: the highlighted cell (A15) has the answer 9 (minimum value = 5+4)
Now I want to add the column name of this minimum value: C.

I am not an excel expert and have no idea how to do this. Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an index/match formula i.e. first find the position of the minimum value in the array using Match, then find the corresponding letter in the header row using Index:

```
=INDEX($B$11:$G$11,MATCH(MIN(TRANSPOSE(B$2:B$7)+$B14:$G14),TRANSPOSE(B$2:B$7)+$B14:$G14,0))
```

Note if ties are possible, this will find the first match.

In my version of Excel, this has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: That's great! Plz accept the answer if it is useful.